# How to get value of a key in c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-code, keyboard

I am trying to detect the keyCode in a program whenever a user enters a key. I am currently using `GetKeyState()` and a bunch of `if-else` ladders.

Is there anyway for me to directly get the keycode of the key pressed so I can reduce the `if-else` ladders? This is what I mean by keycodes, I'm pretty sure they are the decimal conversions of keys:

[image]

Comment: `int code = 'A';` Now `code` is equal to 65. I suppose I don't understand the question.

Comment: What does if-else ladder looks like?

Comment: Please show the actual code that you are trying to simplify.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vaguely worded, but it sounds like you are looking for this method?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-toascii

Something like this should do it I think?

```cpp
char getAsciiKey(UINT virtualKey)
{
  BYTE keyStates[256];

  if(GetKeyboardState(keyStates))
  {
    WORD result[2];
    if(ToAscii(virtualKey, 0, keyStates, result, 0))
    {
      return char(result[0]); //< questionable... :)
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```